my google colab keeps showing "connecting to runtime" is there a way to fix that?
every time I use Google Colab. It allows me to run one cell before the runtime gets disconnected and doesn't connect back. I have found that if I clear all cookies and log in to Google again, I am allowed another cell to run, but it feels way too slow and tedious. Are there any solutions?
I have tried switching networks, and it didn't work. tried changing the runtime, and it didn't work. and I don't see any other real solutions regarding this online
